# File upload fails without error

Tags: upload, filesystem

I try to upload a file larger than the 16 MB Craft limit. The file I try to upload is 61 MB.

I have set the `maxUploadFileSize to 256000000`.
My hosting company changes the server PhP settings to this:

```
max_file_uploads = 20
upload_max_filesize = 256M
max_input_time = 180
memory_limit = 256M
post_max_size = 256M
```

The file starts to upload but when the progress bar is at 50%, it just stops. It keeps "uploading" (wheel keeps spinning in the top right corner) but nothing happens anymore.

I don't get a front-end error either. But in my browser console it says: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Anyone who can help me find a solution?

**UPDATE**

So, my hosting company made the time-out longer and the error dissapeared. 
But I still can't upload the file as I get this error in the console window now:

```
POST http://krycer.be/index.php/admin/actions/assets/uploadFile 502 (Proxy Error ( The specified network name is no longer available.  ))
```

When I diasble my proxy I get this error:

```
POST http://krycer.be/index.php/admin/actions/assets/uploadFile 500 (( The specified network name is no longer available.  ))
```

The file upload completes, but the status bar remains visible, allthough full, and the file is not visible in the assets folder.

Comment: Is it working with smaller images? Do you have access to setting the upload size on the server level?

Comment: It is working with smaller files. I don't have access to the server php settings but previously I got an error saying the file was to big. That's why I mailed the hosting company to adjust the PhP settings and I added the file setting in my general.php So the issue must be something else.

Comment: Do you know if the web server is Apache or Nginx? I ask because I know Nginx has quite a keen timeout default which I usually have to increase.

Comment: Also ask if they have Suhosin or mod_security installed/enabled. They have their own additional settings in addition to the standard php.ini ones.

Comment: They told me that they adjusted the suhosin settings already.

Comment: If it's a one-off case, then might be easier to just FTP the file up and run the "Update Asset Indexes" tool.

Comment: It's not a one off. Tried it already with several different files. It's kind of a problem as my client needs to be able to upload some software and the site is live already. I asked my hosting to look into it too. Anyone else who has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

It would be worth checking `craft/storage/runtime/logs/craft.log`, it's very likely there's a clue in there.

Comment: I don't see any error logs dating to the file upload issue. I asked my hosting if it's apache or nginx. They do both. So awaiting an answer from them.